# Reporte serenity bdd no carga css correctamente

Tags: java, gradle, test, serenity-bdd

Buenas tardes o noches.

Al momento de ejecutar un test usando el framework Serenity BDD no me genera el reporte correctamente ya que no carga los estilos css ni tampoco detalles especificos del reporte de Serenity BDD. Actualmente estoy usando **Java 1.8** y **gradle 7.6**

Adjunto una imagen de reporte que obtengo
[image: Como se puede ver no me carga el archivo css]

Dejo mi configuración en gradle incluyendo la configuración que uso para ejecutar desde consola.

gradle.properties

```
serenityVersion=3.0.0
cucumberVersion=2.6.0
seleniumVersion=3.141.59
junitjupiterVersion=5.7.1
junitVersion=4.13.1
log4jVersion=1.2.17
slf4jVersion=1.7.21
assertjVersion=3.11.1
apachePOIVersion=3.8
apacheOOXMLVersion=3.17
serenityPluginVersion=2.1.4
```

gradle.build

```
plugins{
    id "java"
    id "eclipse"
    id "idea"
    id "net.serenity-bdd.serenity-gradle-plugin" version "3.4.2"
}

group "org.example"
version "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

sourceCompatibility=1.8
targetCompatibility=1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:${junitjupiterVersion}"
    testImplementation "junit:junit:${junitVersion}"
    testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher"
    implementation "org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:${slf4jVersion}"
    implementation "org.assertj:assertj-core:${assertjVersion}"
    implementation "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:${serenityVersion}"
    implementation "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-junit:${serenityVersion}"
    implementation "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-cucumber6:${cucumberVersion}"
    implementation "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-screenplay:${serenityVersion}"
    implementation "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-screenplay-webdriver:${serenityVersion}"
    implementation "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:${seleniumVersion}"
    implementation "io.cucumber:cucumber-java:${cucumberVersion}"
    implementation "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-ensure:${serenityVersion}"
    implementation "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-gradle-plugin:${serenityPluginVersion}"
    implementation "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-single-page-report:${serenityPluginVersion}"
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    maxHeapSize = "1G"
    systemProperty "cucumber.filter.tags", System.getProperty("cucumber.filter.tags")
    testLogging {
        showStandardStreams = true
    }
}

configurations {
    cucumberRuntime {
        extendsFrom testImplementation
    }
}

tasks.register('cucumbercli') {
    dependsOn assemble, testClasses
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = "net.serenitybdd.cucumber.cli.Main"
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            args = [
                    '--plugin', 'pretty',
                    '--glue', 'co.ael.StepsDefinitions',
                    'src/test/resources',
                    '--tags', "${tags}"
            ]
        }
    }
}

test.finalizedBy(aggregate)
```

Configuración que actualmente utilizo en el framework serenity.properties. Ya he usado esta configuración con anterioridad pero ahora me da problemas con lo del reporte.

```
# suppress inspection "UnusedProperty" for whole file
#URLS
webdriver.base.url=**AQUI VA MI URL. NO LA PONGO POR SEGURIDAD**
webdriver.qa.url=
webdriver.prod.url=

#DRIVER SETTINGS
webdriver.driver=chrome
drivers.windows.webdriver.chrome.driver=src/test/resources/webdriver/windows/chromedriver.exe
drivers.mac.webdriver.chrome.driver=src/test/resources/webdriver/mac/chromedriver
drivers.linux.webdriver.chrome.driver=src/test/resources/webdriver/linux/chromedriver
webdriver.autodownload=false
webdriver.timeouts.script=40000
webdriver.timeouts.pageLoad=40000
webdriver.timeouts.implicitlywait=40000
webdriver.timeouts.fluentwait=40000
webdriver.wait.for.timeout=40000

#GOOGLE CHROME SETTINGS
chrome.switches=--incognito;--enable-automation;--no-sandbox;--disable-gpu-sandbox;--start-maximized;--test-type
chrome_preferences.safebrowsing.enabled=FALSE
chrome.capabilities.acceptSslCerts=true
chrome.capabilities.handlesAlerts=true

#SERENITY SETTINGS
feature.file.encoding=UTF-8
narravite.format=asciidoc
restart.browser.each.scenario=true
serenity.store.html.source=true
serenity.reports.show.step.details=true
serenity.console.colors=true
serenity.take.screenshots=FOR_FAILURES
serenity.logging=VERBOSE
serenity.verbose.steps=false
serenity.dry.run=false
serenity.requirement=theme,epic,story
serenity.report.encoding=UTF-8
serenity.browser.maximized=true
serenity.step.delay=3500
story.timeout.in.secs=40000

#JUNIT SETTINGS
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled=false
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default=same_thread
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.classes.default=concurrent

#GRADLE SETTINGS
gradle.startParameter.continueOnFailure=true
cucumber.publish.enabled=true
```

Agradezco sus comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser debido a una incompatibilidad entre la versión del SDK y las dependencias, en mi caso lo hice con maven pero varios compañeros tuvimos error con la versión 17 de java, cambiando la versión funcionó